# File System using composite pattern

Tags: java, composite

I'm trying to build a File system such that contains the following classes: `FileSystem`, `Directory`, `File`.
My code is:

```
public class FileSystem {
    private List<Directory> ld;
    public FileSystem() {
        ld = new ArrayList<Directory>();
    }
    public void addDirectory(Directory dir) {
        ld.add(dir);
    }
    public void showAll() {
        for (Directory directory : ld) {
            directory.showAll();
        }
    }
}

public class File {
    private String fileName;

    public File(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}

public class Directory {
    private String directoryName;
    private List<File> files;
    private List<Directory> subDirs;

    public Directory(String directoryName) {
        this.directoryName = directoryName;
        files = new ArrayList<File>();
        subDirs = new ArrayList<Directory>();
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.directoryName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.directoryName = name;
    }
    // Add and remove files
    public void addFile(File file) {
        files.add(file);
    }
    public void removeFile(File file) {
        files.remove(file);
    }
    // Add and remove directories
    public void addDirectory(Directory dir) {
        subDirs.add(dir);
    }
    public void removeDirectory(Directory dir) {
        subDirs.remove(dir);
    }

    public void showAll() {
        System.out.println(this.directoryName);
        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.println("    " + f.getName());
        }
    }
}

public class Create {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSystem fs = new FileSystem();
        Directory d1 = new Directory("Directory1");

        d1.addFile(new File("FileX"));
        Directory d11 = new Directory("Directory11");
        d11.addFile(new File("File1"));
        d11.addFile(new File("File2"));
        d1.addDirectory(d11);

        fs.addDirectory(d1);
        fs.showAll();
    }
}
```

But when I try to print all the content using the method `showAll` it prints only 'Directory1' and 'FileX', but I want to print:
Directory1
FileX
Directory11
File1
File2

Comment: I wouldn't use `FileSystem` as a separate entity. At least from your example it can be just a `Directory` with the name defining some root like '/'.

Comment: Regarding your question you should use recursion so that you first check if you have any folders and if yes, call `showAll` for all of them, and if not, traverse through files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Directory#showAll` should look like this:

```java
public void showAll() {
    System.out.println(this.directoryName);
    for (File f : files) {
        System.out.println("    " + f.getName());
    }
    for(Directory subDir: subDirs){
        subDir.showAll();
    }
}
```

So it traverses recursively through subDirs also.

**P.S.** - I would also get rid of `FileSystem` entity or at least introduce parent-child relationship between  `Directory` and `FileSystem`

Comment: Now it shows me:  
`Directory11`
`    File1`
`    File2`
`Directory1`
`    FileX`  
And I want:
`Directory1`
`   FileX`
`   Directory11`
`      File1`
`      File2`  
Such that Directory11 is a sub directory of Directory1